# How to reset grafana's admin password (installed by helm)

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-helm

My password once worked, but I don't remember if I changed it or not.

However, I can't reset it.

I tried with no success:

```
kubectl get secret --namespace default grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo 
> DpveUuOyxNrandompasswordYuB5Fs2cEKKOmG <-- does not work (anymore?)
```

PS: I did not set any admin email for web-based reset

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok found.
Best way is to run grafana-cli inside grafana's pod.

```bash
namespace=monitoring
kubectl exec --namespace $namespace -it $(kubectl get pods --namespace $namespace -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -- grafana cli admin reset-admin-password yourNewPasswordHere

INFO[01-21|10:24:17] Connecting to DB                         logger=sqlstore dbtype=sqlite3
INFO[01-21|10:24:17] Starting DB migration                    logger=migrator

Admin password changed successfully ✔
```

Comment: I had to change the cmd line a bit: kubectl exec --namespace prometheus -c grafana -it $(kubectl get pods --namespace prometheus -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -- grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password newpassword

Comment: If we restart deployment data gone. How can i solve it ?

Comment: @kndr it's a different question, you should ask it separately (after probably having a look to persistence in kubernetes volumes)

Comment: @Orkun See my answer. Some helm charts use a secret to store the password. That is why it gets restored after restart.

Answer (score 13):

Okay, try this.

kubectl get pod -n monitoring

kubectl exec -it grafana-00000000aa-lpwkk   -n monitoring -- sh

grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password NEWPASSWORD

Answer (score 2):

If you installed it via kube-prometheus-stack helm chart then the admin password is stored in a secret named `kube-prometheus-stack-grafana`. You need to set it there are restart the Grafana pod.

Alternatively, you can just decode the password and use:

`kubectl get secrets/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'`

If you are using k9s, you can select the secret and press `x` to base64 decode it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to decode the secret and change the password from grafana dashboard
kubectl get secret loki-grafana -n loki -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode